# disposing Func<T> registration in autofac

Tags: c#, autofac, func

I'm registering a `func<Task<T>>` with autofac in a ASP.NET Core server.

I want to use the registration in multiple places but I only want to invoke the task once, the problem is the result never gets disposed

registration code:

```
 var getItemMethod = GetType()
                .GetMethod(nameof(GetItem), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .MakeGenericMethod(resultType);

builder.Register(c => getItemMethod.Invoke(this, new[] { c.Resolve(resultType), task}))
                        .As(importResultDelegate)
                        .InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope(SCOPE_TAG);

private Func<T> GetItem<T>(object obj, MethodInfo task)
            where T : class
{
  T output = null;
  return () => output ?? ((T)task.Invoke(obj, null))
      .Tee(o => output = o);
}
```

usage code:

```
public Constructor(Func<Task<Object>> objectFac)

var data = await objectFac();
```

this is called within

```
using(var inner = scope.BeginLifetimeScope(SCOPE_TAG){}
```

that causes a memory leak in the server as the  `T output` is never disposed

I tried to use `.OnRelease` but it never gets called.

Comment: If `T` is disposable, you need to dispose of it yourself.

Comment: Could you clarify what resultType, importResultDelegate, task and T.Tee() are in your code? They don't compile and might explain a few things. Generally, Autofac will dispose of IDisposables resolved from a context, including those accessed via a resolved Func<T> but there's a lot going on here which could get in the way. What's the use-case you're really solving for? Is it really just a factory for a Func<Task<T>> where T is a specific type? There might be a simpler way to represent the factories more natively via Autofac where you're less likely to hit these issues at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get it disposed by `Autofac`, you need to use a class that implements `IDisposable` instead of `Func<T>`. From [Autofac documentation](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/disposal.html):

> To take advantage of automatic deterministic disposal, your component
>   must implement IDisposable.

Otherwise you need manually dispose `T` object produced by your factory.

Comment: I'm aware of that. I tried using onRelease but that never gets called

Comment: `T output` is not going to be managed by Autofac *at all*.  Autofac cannot know whe you're done with that object.  If it's disposable, you must dispose of it yourself.

Comment: got it. so is there a way I can dispose of ```T output``` of the factory when the LifetimeScope is disposed? @Amy